# Help me finding associated matrix for the linear function

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the associated matrix for the linear function $L_1 : R^3 →R^3$ given by $L_1(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$ in the basis ${(6,0,7),(−1,4,0),(0,15,−31)}$ (used on both the domain and codomain). Prove that ${(6,0,7),(−1,4,0),(0,15,−31)}$ is the basis for $R^3$.

I know how to prove basis by proving its linearly independence by letting equations all equal to zero and show trivial solutions but I am not sure how to find associated matrix?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assign $w_1=(6,0,7)$, $w_2=(-1,4,0)$, and $w_3=(0,15,-31)$. Since these vectors are the basis for both the domain and the codomain, we will plug these vectors into the equation $L_1$ and then solve the system of equations $aw_1+bw_2+cw_3$ where a,b,c $\in$ $R$. For example, for our first equation let's denote our a,b,c as $a_1, b_1, c_1$ we plug in $w_1$ to get

$L_1(w_1)=(0,7,6)=a_1w_1+b_1w_2+c_1w_3$

This will produce the system of equations

$6a_1-b_1+0c_1=0$

$0a_1+4b_1+15c_1=7$

$7a_1+0b_1-31c_1=6$

Solving this system of equations will give us our first column $
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} \\
a_{2} \\
a_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
 Repeat this for each vector (I.E. $L_1(w_2), L_1(w_3)$) to get the full matrix
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

To more generally answer this, given a linear transformation $L:V->W$ with finite basis $B_v={v_1,...,v_m}$ for V and $B_w={w_1,w_2,...,w_n}$ for W, we can find the associated matrix by solving the series of equations $L(v_1)=(a_{1,1})w_1+...+(a_{1,n})w_n$, and the corresponding first column will be
$
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{1,1} \\
...\\
a_{1,n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$, with all $a_{i,j}$ being in the reals. We will repeat this process m times to find our m x n associated matrix, 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{m,1} \\
a_{1,2} & \dots & a_{m,2} \\
\dots & \dots & \dots \\
a_{1,n} & \dots & a_{m,n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Sorry for the poor formatting, I've never used Latex before and can't really dedicate the time to learn it right now. I hope this helps out a bit at least!